# Surface scanning

Tags: sensor, raspberry-pi

I’d like to build a bowling ball surface scanner as a home project. Similar to a CD player using a semiconductor diode laser and a small photoelectric cell to read the surface. I would like to read what the grit is at and if possible view the bumps. Any tips or suggestions would helpful to find the correct electronics I would need.

Comment: You would not use a photoelectric cell. You would use a photodiode. I would try this self-mixing method using a laser diode with integrated photodiode: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MUdro-6u2Zg

Comment: If you do not have an oscilloscope, you will need to save up for one. This project won't be possible without it.

Comment: Figure out how it is done.https://www.jayhawkbowling.com/Products/Surface_Scanner.html

Comment: The CD pickup is a good idea since it can track a surface that is not moving completely uniformly about the acis of rotation (e.g. if your bearings aren't extremely smooth or your ball isn't perfectly spherical) while still reading out local shape profile. I think this will be a complex project however.